# How can I sort an event by id (descending) in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How can I sort an event by id in DESC order?

My all events are coming and by default they are sort by ASC order and I want to Sort events by DESC order. So that my latest event will show first.

Code I have used,

```
if(jQuery().fullCalendar) {        
    eventOrder: "eventOrder",
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [`eventOrder`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/) documentation.

> a name of an Event Object property, like "title". This can be the name of a non-standard field. Sorting will happen in ascending order. If prefixed with a minus sign like "-title", sorting will happen in descending order.

so you will set -

```
eventOrder: "-id",
```